# Expanded List with TreeMap in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am using the 'expanded' form of <#list>:

```
<#list hubId.list>
<select name="hubname" id="${hubId.id}">
<#items as hubname>
  <option value="${hubname.id}">${hubname.name}</option>
</#items>
</select>
<#else>
<p>There are no Hubs available.</p>
</#list>
```

Research tells that iterating over `hubId.list`, which is a TreeMap, is problematic.
"Freemarker template error: Expected a sequence or collection..."

The solution is to use `?keys as key`. But in this form of <#list> what would be the solution, if this form is the most appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, because there is no example of that case in the documentation.

You can use  [`values`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html#ref_builtin_values) built-in, like that:

```
<#list hubId.list?values>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to list the `?keys` as `hubname`, and then use `hubId.list[hubname]` to get the value. Not very nice, but... that's how it is.